# Driving Route From my location to multiples markers android

Tags: android

I I followed this tutorial http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/ and it is very useful.I had two marker showing the driving route, where one is the origen and the other is the destiny.
I created a new arrayList(location) wherer i added my Markers and created a onMarkerClick for the markers that i have created. 
on my onMarkerclick LatLng title = marker.getPosition();

```
    if (title.equals("Loja Coqueiros") && markerPoints.size() < 2 ){

        LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
        LatLng dest = locations.get(1);

        // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
        String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
        downloadTask.execute(url);
```

but whem a click my markers the route just point to one marker that i added to arrayList(location).

I want to know how can i make to click each one of my markers and show the driving route from my location to each one of my markers.

any doubt please ask me, I'm not very good in English
help me please

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

```
GoogleMap map;

ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;


ArrayList<LatLng> locations;
ArrayList<LatLng> locations2;


private static final LatLng LOJACOQUEIRO = new LatLng(-08.8123083,13.2249500);
private static final LatLng LOJAAMILCACABRAL = new LatLng(-08.8265861,13.2274667);
private static final LatLng LOJASAMBA = new LatLng(-08.8328611,13.2182861);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    GoogleMap mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener((GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) this);


    Marker marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOJACOQUEIRO).title("Loja Coqueiros").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_marker)));
    Marker marker2 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOJAAMILCACABRAL).title("Loja Amilca Cabral").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_marker)));
    Marker marker3 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOJASAMBA).title("Loja samba").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_marker)));


    // Initializing
    markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    // Inicializing Array of Unitel lojas Lat and Long
    locations = new ArrayList();
    locations2 = new ArrayList();


    // add the Lat and Long of Lojas
    locations.add(LOJACOQUEIRO);
    locations.add(LOJAAMILCACABRAL);
    locations.add(LOJASAMBA);



    // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);


    // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
    map = fm.getMap();

    if (map != null) {

        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Setting onclick event listener for the map
        map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                // Already two locations
                if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                    markerPoints.clear();

                    map.clear();


                } //if (locations.size()>0) {
```

//                        map.
//                    }

```
                // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                markerPoints.add(point);

                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOJACOQUEIRO).title("Loja Coqueiros").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_marker)));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOJAAMILCACABRAL).title("Loja Amilca Cabral").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_marker)));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOJASAMBA).title("Loja samba").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_marker)));

                // Creating MarkerOptions
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                // Setting the position of the marker
                options.position(point);

                /**
                 * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
                 * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
                 */
                if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                    options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                }

                // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                map.addMarker(options);

                // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                    LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                    LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                    // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                    String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                    // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                    downloadTask.execute(url);
                } //if (locations.size())
            }
        });
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

   LatLng title = marker.getPosition();


        if (title.equals("Loja Coqueiros") && markerPoints.size() < 2 ){

        LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
        LatLng dest = locations.get(1);

        // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
        String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
        downloadTask.execute(url);
    }
    return false;


}



private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

    // Origin of route
    String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

    // Destination of route
    String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

    // Sensor enabled
    String sensor = "sensor=false";

    // Building the parameters to the web service
    String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

    // Output format
    String output = "json";

    // Building the url to the web service
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

    return url;
}
/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}



// Fetches data from url passed
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    // Downloading data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        try{
            // Fetching the data from web service
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
    // doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}

/** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

    // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

            // Starts parsing data
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        // Traversing through all the routes
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            // Fetching i-th route
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

            // Fetching all the points in i-th route
            for(int j=0;j<path.size();j++){
                HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
            lineOptions.addAll(points);
            lineOptions.width(3);
            lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
        }

        // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
        map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
```

//     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }`enter code here`
}

Comment: as you are requesting for directions initially .do it for each of new marker from your initial point . and you will get the path.

Comment: I'm using arrayList because I want to create more than 10 marker if I do to
each marker my code will be very long

Comment: no you have to call the same function 10 times . your code will never be longer.

Comment: I have to call 10 times inside the onMarkerClick?

Comment: yes @Eudes you have to call as many times as you need path . just change some parameters and then you are good to go.

Comment: i have all my markers in my arrayList. Could you give a exemple how to do it please.

Comment: yes sure . i will give an answer to your question .

Comment: Sagar Nayak please give a exemple